# Is CDSSO logic valid in same domain?

Tags: openam, opensso

I have my agent installed in domain 1, and OpenSSO in domain 2, and their is a VPN connection established between the two. So in this scenario will the normal SSO work or CDSSO. I tested and find normal SSO works fine and able to get cookie, but in CDSSO i get 403x error.

Answer (score 0):

You can either configure agent in CDSSO or SSO mode when the resource protected by the agent is located in the same cookie domain ... but it does not make sense. CDSOO is only needed to transfer the SSO tracking cookie in the other cookie domain.

However I suspect you get '#403x' error which is due to agent profile property 'agent root url for CDSSO' does not match the value for 'ProviderID' in the request hitting the CDCServlet.

Comment: I am able to solve 403X error, but now I am getting 403 access denied error debuger says the following cause for it "One or more AuthnResponse conditions might not have been met. Denying  to requested URI - /agentapp/sunwCDSSORedirectURI", but I am using "SSO_ONLY",so why it is checking conditions?